# Binary not optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, validation, launchimage

Getting error "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5..." Tried solutions listed in previous posts but validation error persists. Will try upgrading to Xcode 6 but looking for other possible remedies.

In a launch image set in asset catalogue I have the following:

`Default.png` for the 1x: 3.5 inch: (340x480)

`Default@2x.png` for the 2x: 3.5 inch retina: (640x960)

`Default-568h@2x.png`  for the R4: 4 inch retina: (640x1136)

Under Attributes Inspector I've clicked on `iPhone Portrait` for both "iOS 7 and later" and "iOS 6 and Prior"

Comment: All those launch images have correct size, Did you try clearing Xcode? if press and hold ALT key while opening product menu you will see Clear Build Folder.

Comment: Sometimes you simply need to delete the entire derived data directory too.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If so, how?